# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException - Query parameter not found

Tags: php, jasper-reports, jasperserver, php-java-bridge

I use JasperServer and PHP JavaBridge to generate PDF reports via JasperServer inside PHP. I get compile error because of missing (unassigned) parameter passed to JRXML compiler

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:
"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: 
[[c:JasperCompileManager]]->compileReport((o:String)[o:String]). 
Cause: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: 
**Report design not valid** : 1. **Query parameter not found** : db_field_id VM: 
1.6.0_18@http://java.sun.com/" at: #-12
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:258)
```

I cant find a way to pass my

```
$params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
foreach ($jrxml_params as $key => $jr_param) $params->put($key, $jr_param);
```

list of params to the compile method nor I can disable this verification by

```
$japser_props = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRProperties");
$japser_props->COMPILER_XML_VALIDATION  = false;
```

Here is what I use to generate PDF (works fine if JRXML file doesn't contain $P{} pamareters and halts otherwise)

```
$class = new JavaClass("java.lang.Class");
$class->forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
$driverManager = new JavaClass("java.sql.DriverManager");
$conn = $driverManager->getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XXX?user=XXX&password=1234");

$compileManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
$report = $compileManager->compileReport(realpath("/www/some.jrxml"));

$params = new Java("java.util.HashMap");
foreach ($jrxml_params as $key => $jr_param) $params->put($key, $jr_param); 

$jasperPrint = $fillManager->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);
$exportManager = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager");
$outputPath = realpath(".")."/"."output.pdf";
$exportManager->exportReportToPdfFile($jasperPrint, $outputPath);
```

How do I avoid this error, I know what I need to pass and I don't know a way to do it, can't I just pass params to fillManager?

Answer (score 1):

```
$japser_props = new JavaClass("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRProperties");
$japser_props->setProperty('net.sf.jasperreports.compiler.xml.validation',true);
```

this is the way to set property from PHP but that's not the problem. It turns out everything was fine, I've missed parameter declaration before my MySQL query... Put

```
<parameter name="db_field_id" class="java.lang.Integer">
```

in your JRXML before you use it as $P{db_field_id} now it compliles fine and later

```
$jasperPrint = $fillManager->fillReport($report, $params, $conn);
```

parameters are assigned at fill time